# UIScrollView not moving

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am trying to scroll the view up when the keyboard covers a "textfield". I have a setter to determine which "textfield" is active (as Apple's documentation instructed). When I try to use method "scrollRectToVisible" nothing happens. I used `NSLog` to test when the view should and shouldn't move. The rest of the program seems to work fine. I don't understand what I did wrong. Could this be caused by using storyboard with auto layout enabled?

```
if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
 [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:activeField.frame animated:YES]; //not working
    NSLog(@"View Should Move");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you want your scrollView to move up when the keyboard appears , you  could add the keyboard height to your scrollview's current content Offset and set your scrollViews contentOffset to the new offset value. ` 
        [self.scrollView setContentOffset:newOffset animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the rect is *already* visible (it is within the scroll view's bounds), so nothing happens.

The fact that the keyboard will cover it is irrelevant to the concept "visible" as used in `scrollRectToVisible:`.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to just use a third party helper to scroll your scrollView when ever a textField is tapped. Try [THIS](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) just download the files and set your scrollView's subclass to TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView . It works like a charm.